# How to Search and Hide on Blogger Posting

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I have Table on my blogger post.

I give it an Input form to it. Reader can search data quickly.

I get code from W3school.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table

[W3school](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ayTx.jpg)
This code run well. But I need some improvement.

The Question:

1. How to show the Table just when user click "Enter Key" on Input/Button Form.
2. And when Input Form is empty, the Table automatically Hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will trigger search only when you hit "Enter Key" on Input.
Table automatically hides when search text is removed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput"  placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">


<table id="myTable" style="display:none;">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

 input = document.getElementById("myInput");
   if(input.value.length <1){
     document.getElementById("myTable").style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }
  else if (event.keyCode === 13) {
     // Cancel the default action, if needed
     event.preventDefault();     
     myFunction();
    }
});

function myFunction() {

  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase(); 
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");  
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
  document.getElementById("myTable").style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are kind. This what I find. And you solve my problem. BIG THANKS from me Brother.

Comment: More power to you! This community is obliged to help people. An upvote is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See the below code. I hope it will be solve your issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 10px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }

    #myTable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    #myTable th,
    #myTable td {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 12px;
    }

    #myTable tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    #myTable tr.header,
    #myTable tr:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>My Customers</h2>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
      <td>Sweden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>North/South</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paris specialites</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <style>
    #myTable {
      display: none;
    }

    #myTable.hide {
      display: table;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
          txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }

      var inputvalues = $("#myInput").val();
      if (inputvalues.length > 0) {
        $("#myTable").addClass("hide");
      }
      if(inputvalues == "" || inputvalues== null)
      $("#myTable").removeClass("hide");
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You gave me a solution Bro.

Comment: If you sastisy with my sol. please vote me on my answered.

Comment: Ok. But I do not know how to do it. Can you guide me how?